# How can I configure UltraMon so that UltraMon taskbars are in the same order than the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar, ultramon

Windows 7 cannot natively display a taskbar to each of my monitors, so I use [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)'s multi-taskbars feature. How can I configure UltraMon so that the applications in the UltraMon taskbars are in the same order than the applications in the the Windows taskbar?

UltraMon taskbars:

[image]

Windows taskbar:

[image]

I use UltraMon 3.2.2 x64 with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to configure UltraMon so that UltraMon taskbars are in the same order than the Windows taskbar.